# smart alternative to setTimeout

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

I'm using some software where it is possible to add some custom script. After some trial and error I found out that this script only work if I put it like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
//code
}, 900);
```

But I find this a little bit ugly, and I feel like it should be possible to do it smarter. I also don't know if at other computers I may need longer time. Maybe for someone else I need to set it to 5000, and for some other one it is okay to have it at 300.

Is it possible to fire the function after everything is loaded ? 
This method, I tried, but didn't work:
`$(document).ready(function(){ .. });`
`document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {...}, false);`

Here is my complete code:

```
setTimeout(function(){
function correct(searchString, replaceString) {
    $("textarea").bind("keyup", function () {
        var $input = $(this),text = $input.val();
        var pos = $(this).prop("selectionStart");
        if (new RegExp(searchString).test(text.substring(pos-searchString.length,pos)) == true) {
            var newText = text.substring(0,pos-searchString.length) + replaceString + text.substring(pos);
            $input.val(newText);
            var newpos = pos - searchString.length + replaceString.length;
            this.setSelectionRange(newpos,newpos);
        }
    });
}
correct("RR", "ℝ");
correct(">=","≥");
}, 900);
```

I have set this as a custom header in a discourse forum (discourse.org)

Comment: Have you tried just putting it in a "ready" handler? `$(function() { /* your code here */ });`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes, doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried putting it after your jQuery inclusion script?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is going to be hooking into the `window.onload` event:

```
// cross-browser event listener
function addEvent(evnt, elem, func) {
   if (elem.addEventListener)  // W3C DOM
      elem.addEventListener(evnt,func,false);
   else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
      elem.attachEvent("on"+evnt, func);
   }
   else { // No much to do
      elem[evnt] = func;
   }
}
// add the actual event
addEvent('load', window, function(){
    // execute your code here
})
```

Comment: I don't see any textarea's on that page to bind to, try replacing your calls to `correct` with: `console.log("Loaded");`

Comment: It appears to work for me now that you've added the `alert`. Perhaps the binding isn't working as intended

Comment: haha, it so strange, you have been on my site. You'll see that sometimes addevent load first, and sometimes settimeout loads first. Sometimes addevent works, and sometimes it doesn't very strange.

Comment: addEvent will get called once the entire page has loaded, setTimeout will be called regardless. Whether or not the DOM is ready for you to target & manipulate when your setTimeout executes is fully dependent on how long the server takes to render the DOM; addEvent will **always** work, but it will take a variable amount of time depending on the server response time

Comment: I mean, the alert happens. So the addEvent does work. But it seems like it sometimes just too early. Because sometimes the keybindings work and sometimes they don't. At least in chrome, it is 50-50. In firefox it works all the time. And in IE it never works.

Comment: It is very strange, I've extended function so that it also binds the keys in every input field, and it works now in the search bar with your addevent function: http://mathematics.discoursehosting.net/?preview-style=f4ec21ea-0755-4edc-900c-f49398b7f079 but in the textarea it still doesn't work all the time in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Execute on document ready.

```
function correct(searchString, replaceString) {
    $("textarea").bind("keyup", function () {
        var $input = $(this),text = $input.val();
        var pos = $(this).prop("selectionStart");
        if (new RegExp(searchString).test(text.substring(pos-searchString.length,pos)) == true) {
            var newText = text.substring(0,pos-searchString.length) + replaceString + text.substring(pos);
            $input.val(newText);
            var newpos = pos - searchString.length + replaceString.length;
            this.setSelectionRange(newpos,newpos);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  correct("RR", "ℝ");
  correct(">=","≥");
});
```

Comment: This hasn't been tagged for jquery, not sure if the asker has access to it as they are posting on a site they don't control

Comment: document.ready should fire once all of a page's resources have finished loading and have been parsed.  Do you have some other javascript which runs on ready, then?

Comment: Whats the sequence for loading the script you are waiting? I mean, you can always use window.onload event handler. By the way, are you loading that particular script on demand or you have a script tag?

Comment: @Ryan This is the website: http://mathematics.discoursehosting.net/ But I haven't made the software myself.

Comment: Ok, from the console I see you have jQuery 2.0.3, what browser are you using?

Comment: @CharlieAffumigato Chrome